# Tweepy OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE Native App - what values do I use for Callback URI/Redirect URL & Website URL?

Tags: python, oauth-2.0, oauth, tweepy, twitter-oauth

I am trying to do [OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (User Context) using Tweepy](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html#oauth-2-0-authorization-code-flow-with-pkce-user-context)

While setting this up in the Twitter Developer Portal, I choose Type of App as Native App

[image: Type of App]

But I still get asked for Callback URI/Redirect URL & Website URL?

[image: URIs & URLs]

Since it's a native app, I am not sure what values I give here. I am trying to build a non-UI console app which will run from the command line - i.e. no URLs & no UIs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are sure that you can not use the classic 3-legged OAuth process, you will have to use a PIN-based authorization (see the Tweepy documentation [here](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/authentication.html#pin-based-oauth)).

So, since you have to use `"oob"` as a callback URL in your code, I would suggest you to try to do the same in that dashboard page. If that does not work (which is the more likely hypothesis), you can probably set a *lorem ipsum* URL (for example  `http://localhost`) since you will never use it.

Comment: I want to use the bookmarks API (get_bookmarks). I was going through this - https://improveandrepeat.com/2022/07/python-friday-131-working-with-bookmarks-in-tweepy/ - it suggested -  OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (User Context)

Comment: @user93353 The choice between OAuth 1.0a and OAuth 2.0 with PKCE is supposed to be distinct from how you get the confirmation (PIN or callback). While this is not clearly documented in the Tweepy documentation, you should be able to mix their example for the OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE (User Context) and their example for the PIN-based OAuth.

Comment: Are you saying i can use the classic 3-legged OAuth process for get_bookmarks or not? Also what is "oob"?

Comment: @user93353 No, you can't use it without a callback URL. My suggestion is to try to use a PIN 3-legged OAuth process for your OAuth 2.0 Authorization Code Flow with PKCE. And "oob" is the callback parameter to set if you want to use a PIN-base authorization.